# android share audio file from assets folder

Tags: java, android, gradle, facebook-android-sdk, javafxports

I can't share audio file from assets.
Each app says that it can't send the file.

Method for converting inputstream to temporary file

```
    public File getFile(String Prefix, String Suffix) throws IOException {

    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(Prefix, Suffix);
    AssetFileDescriptor tempafd = FXActivity.getInstance().getAssets().openFd(filepath);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    IOUtils.copy(tempafd.createInputStream(), out);


    return tempFile;
}
```

Sharing file

```
        item2.setOnAction(n ->{
            try {
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tekst.getFile(tekst.getFilename(), ".mp3"));
                Intent share = new Intent();
                share.setType("audio/*");
                share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                FXActivity.getInstance().startActivity(share);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainCategoryCreator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can u check tekst.getFilename().mp3 file exists or not. I mean your temp file exists or not and check the size of the file to confirm its not corrupted?

Comment: Yes it exists because it have the same size that the original one from assets.

Comment: @Raghavendra so what can cause that ?

Comment: Can u tell me where u r creating the temp file? Can u post the sample path?

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389696/3956070)? I'm not sure if creating the temporal file in an external public folder could work.

Comment: I dont place temp file in any directory. I have to rather first import assets to external storage.

Comment: I've tested with an audio file placed in the app assets folder, and the temp file is created in the local private path of the app. Print the Uri and you will see. That can't be accessed externally.

Comment: So i have to place temp file in external directory

Comment: Yes and no: Not necessarily in the external storage, but at least into your internal files dir (via `Context.getFilesDir()`). From there, there are sophisticated means in the Android world to share your content. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just as it happens, I struggled with almost an identical problem: I needed to share a video file. The problem is: There is now way to share an internal file. Never.
You either need a `ContentProvider`, or since it's a bit simpler with it, it's extension `FileProvider`.

First: you need to update you `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="my.package.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

This needs to be added into the `<application>`tag.

Then you need the XML file `file_paths.xml` in the Android sub-directory `res/xml/`

It should something like this:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="objects" path="objects/"/>
</paths>
```

And to finally trigger it, I needed to call it like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://my.package.fileprovider/" + fn); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); // or parse uri each time
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*"); // all video type == * - alternative: mp4, ...
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = FXActivity.getInstance().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    FXActivity.getInstance().grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
FXActivity.getInstance().startActivity(intent);
```

But what I needed to do prior to be able to use it like this: I needed to copy all assets to the private files dir, because the `FileProvider` itself has no option to access your assets (I guess you could achieve this with a custom `ContentProvider`, but I found way to complicated and didn't have that much time).

See [this Android Developer reference on FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) for mor information.

My simple solution for this looks like this:

```
public boolean copyAssetsToStorage() throws NativeServiceException {
    try {
        String[] assets = getContext().getAssets().list(DIR_NAME);
        if (assets == null || assets.length == 0) {
            LOG.warning("No assets found in '" + DIR_NAME + "'!");
            return false;
        }
        File filesDir = getContext().getFilesDir();
        File targetDir = new File(filesDir, DIR_NAME);
        if (!targetDir.isDirectory()) {
            boolean b = targetDir.mkdir();
            if (!b) {
                LOG.warning("could not create private directory with the name '" + DIR_NAME + "'!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (String asset : assets) {
            File targetFile = new File(targetDir, asset);
            if (targetFile.isFile()) {
                LOG.info("Asset " + asset + " already present. Nothing to do.");
                continue;
            } else {
                LOG.info("Copying asset " + asset + " to private files.");
            }
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                is = getContext().getAssets().open(DIR_NAME + "/" + asset);
                os = new FileOutputStream(targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = is.read(buff)) > 0)
                    os.write(buff, 0, len);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
                continue;
            }
            if (os != null) {
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            }
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        }
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I only support a flat hierarchy for now...

This at least did the trick for me.

Regards,
Daniel

---

***ADDIDIONAL QUESTION***: Why are you sending an Intent and not implement a simple JavaFX audio player control? This is what I did prior to the Video stuff.